# Could this be factored any further?

Tags: fractions

My friend recently told me that $\frac{-x}{x}$ could not be simplified any further. Is he correct or could it be simplified such that the answer isn't undefined when you `x=0`?

Comment: sometimes this is called signum, abbreviated sgn, with $\operatorname{sgn} x = 1$ if $x>0,$ $\operatorname{sgn} x = 0$ if $x=0,$ and  $\operatorname{sgn} x = -1$ if $x<0.$ Related to the Heaviside function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function

Comment: It's $-1$ when $x \ne 0$, and undefined when $x = 0$. Usually, people will say that it can be simplified to $-1$, and write $-x/x = -1, x \ne 0$.

Comment: As a member of the field ${\mathbb F}(x)$ of rational functions in indeterminate $x$ over field $\mathbb F$, it is equal to $-1$.

Comment: Oh, I automatically inserted absolute values in the denominator, not really there. That's life...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is how it is $$-  \frac{x}{x} = \begin{cases} -1 & \text{if} & x \neq 0 \\ \text{undefined} & \text{if} & x = 0 \end{cases}$$